# What is happening to the function arguments with stacked python decorators?

Tags: python, arguments, decorator, wrapper, python-3.7

I can't figure out how to pass the original arguments to stacked decorators. Here is my example:

```
def outside_decorator(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('outside args:',inspect.getfullargspec(function).args)
        return function(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper

def inside_decorator(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def innerwrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        print('inside args:', inspect.getfullargspec(function).args)
        return function(*args,**kwargs)
    return innerwrapper

class trial:
    @outside_decorator
    @inside_decorator
    def __init__(self,val1,val2,val3,note1='hello',note2='hi'):
        print('decorated function args:',inspect.getfullargspec(trial).args)
        print('arg values:',val1, val2, val3, note1, note2)

a=trial(1,2,3)
```

The output is:

```
outside args: []
inside args: ['self', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'note1', 'note2']
decorated function args: []
arg values: 1 2 3 hello hi
```

I've seen some answers that cite an error with `@functools.wraps()` and  involve the decorator module with `@decorator.decorator` to decorate the decorators, but it's making it so the decorator or wrapper only take allow positional argument input. I've tried every combination, but I can't make heads or tails of it.

How can I preserve the arguments through stacked decorators?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your decorators don't take any arguments. If you get rid of that `inspect...`, and just print `args` and `kwargs` you can see you already have access to the args.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you realise that a decorator just takes the function as an argument, so your `trial.__init__()` method is actually `outside_decorator(inside_decorator(trial.__init__(*args, **kwargs)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example how to use parameters in decorators in Python:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-with-parameters-in-python/

Please keep in mind that everything is an object in Python and when you try to decorate a function with another function in Python, it means that you just use the inner function as a parameter for outer function.